# Unchecked all check boxes whose checked when click on other checkbox is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have 4 check boxes, I want to uncheck all check boxes whose checked when click on **None** checkbox.

Issue is that when I checked **Option1** and **Option2** checkboxes and when I checked on **None** checkbox then **Option1** and **Option2** checkboxes is not unchecked.

When I check checkboxes which value is **2** and **3** then when I check checkbox which value is **4** so **2** and **3** checkboxes will be uncheck

```
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none" value="1">Option 1
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none" value="2">Option 2
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none" value="3">Option 3
<input class="form-check-input tab1_chk example" type="checkbox" name="2[]" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" id="none" value="4">None
```

here is my jquery code

```
<script>
        function uncheckOthers(ele) {  
        if(ele.checked && ele.value == "4") { // check #none is checked and has its value 4
        ele.checked = false;
            $('.example').prop('checked', false);// Uncheck all the checkboxes with class 'example'
        }
    };


    </script>
```

Note: My checkboxes is dynamic from database that's why I write this

Comment: your question was not clear and useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 1" value="1">Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 2" value="2">Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 3" value="3">Option 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="uncheckOthers(this)" class='termcls' name="None" id="none" value="4">None<br>
    <script>
        function uncheckOthers(ele) {  
            if(ele.checked && ele.value == "4") { // check #none is checked and has its value 4
                $('.example').prop('checked', false);// Uncheck all the checkboxes with class 'example'
            }
        };
    </script>
```

*other Way , you pass the custom value in onchange function. And you can check the condition as follows*

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="uncheckOthers(this,4)" class='termcls' name="None" id="none" value="4">None<br>


function uncheckOthers(ele,checkValue) {  
    if(ele.checked && ele.value == checkValue) { 
         $('.example').prop('checked', false);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for supporting but still not working. check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/phcrh2ds/ as your answer

Comment: I'm not sure why its not working in jsfiddle. But its working for me in my HTML page.

Comment: @Arslan, In your jsfiddle link, Jquery library is not loaded and change the load type as "No wrap - in <head>". Change the settings accordingly in script section. then it will work

Comment: its working perfectly on fiddle as per my requirements but issue is that in my html page when check on none checkbox then other  checked checkboxes is unchecked but none checkbox is not checked

Comment: All checkboxes is checked but none checkbox is not checked even I check this at first time

Comment: Please update your above answer as per working fiddle then I maked it useful for others

Comment: Yes same happening in my html page. None checkbox is not checked when click on it

Comment: remove this line  ele.checked = false;

Comment: I removed this line but still none checkbox is not working as checkbox working in html

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign a value to the checkbox. Instead, you can check whether the checkbox with id 'none' is checked and then uncheck all the checkboxes with class "example".

```js
function uncheckOthers() {
  // check whether checkbox with id 'none' is checked.
  if($("#none").is(':checked')) {
    $('input.example').prop('checked', false);// Uncheck all the checkboxes with class 'example'
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 1" value="1">Option 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 2" value="2">Option 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 3" value="3">Option 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="uncheckOthers()" class='termcls' id="none">None
```

Uncheck using checkbox value.

```js
function uncheckOthers() {
  // check whether checkbox with id 'none' is checked and it's value is 4.
  if($("#none").is(':checked') && $("#none").val() == 4) {    
    $('input.example').each(function () {
      if($(this).val() == 3 || $(this).val() == 2) {// Check the value is 2 or 3
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 1" value="1">Option 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 2" value="2">Option 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="example" name="Option 3" value="3">Option 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="uncheckOthers()" class='termcls' id="none" value="4">None
<input type="checkbox" onchange="uncheckOthers()" class='termcls' id="none1" value="5">None1
```

Comment: Is there any way to uncheck by value?

Comment: @Arslan what do you mean by 'uncheck by value'? Do you need to uncheck only some checkboxes depending on their value?

Comment: Yes I need to uncheck some checkboxes depending on their value

Comment: @Arslan Yes you can. Check the updated answer. In the second snippet, we check whether the checkbox value is 3 and then uncheck only that checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for supporting But I need checkbox which id is none, assign a value of 4, when I checked this checkbox then checked checkboxes will be uncheck

Comment: Suppose: I checked checkboxes which value is 2 and 3 then I check checkbox which value is 4 so 2 and 3 value checkbox will be uncheck

Comment: @Arslan I am not sure about your requirement. But check again updated second snippet. It checks whether the checkbox with id none is checked and its value is 4. Then it unchecks checkboxes with values 2 and 3.